# Understanding asymptotic notation

Tags: algorithm, runtime, notation

If you have this expression:
O(n^4) + Ω(n^2).

Does that men that the runtime is somewhere between n^4 and n^2?
Or is it that it can be either:
from n^2 to infinity,
or from n^4 to 1?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: You never meet such expressions, unless in error.

Answer (score 2):

The statement *f(n) = O(n^4) + Ω(n^2)* means that *f* can be expressed as the sum of two functions:

- *f(n) = g(n) + h(n)*;
- *g(n) = O(n^4)*;
- *h(n) = Ω(n^2)*.

Assuming *g* and *h* are both nonnegative, it follows that *f >= h* and *f >= g*. Since *h(n) = Ω(n^2)*, it is also true that *f(n) = Ω(n^2)*; this is a property of *Ω( )* which can be easily proven from its definition. However, *f(n) >= g(n)* and *g(n) = O(n^4)* do not give us any more information on *f*.

So the only thing we can say is:

*f(n) = Ω(n^2)*

Comment: If you allow negative g, Ω(n²) is not even guaranteed !

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes, in a more mathy context I would not assume g and h to be nonnegative unless explicitly stated. But given the "algorithm" and "runtime" tags of the question it sounds reasonable. Maybe the author of the statement had an algorithm consisting in two parts; they proved the first part runs in O(n^4); they proved the second part runs in Ω(n^2); they concluded the algorithm runs in O(n^4) + Ω(n^2); then they didn't know what to do with that info and left it there. Then the OP read the proof and got confused.

Comment: Don't worry, I know :-)

Comment: It was a task for an assignment, im a pretty fresh student in computer science, so i dont know what you're talking about here in the last comment, but just thought i should let you know :)